# how to get value from local variable in success function of jquery request

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably a basic question because I'm not particularly good at javascript and don't understand closures etc. So I'm having trouble getting variable values to pass into the call backs. In this code, how can I get the value of id to pass to the success function handler so it's available when the function returns back?

```
 $(document).on("click","#media-edit-form .fancybox-submit", function(event){
        var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
        var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        var postData = form.serializeArray();
        var id = postData["id"];

        event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

        var jqxhr = $.ajax(
            {
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: postData,
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
            }

         )
            .success(function(xhr) {

                var refreshZoneId = '#image-block' + id;
                var refreshZone = $(refreshZoneId);
                alert('refreshing');


            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
            });
    });
```

Comment: value of id should be available in the success callback.. what is the problem you are facing

Comment: @ArunPJohny is right. This appears to be a closure, so the variable should be in scope.

Comment: I think the problem is `postData["id"]` - [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) returns an array not an object so `postData["id"]` should return undefined

Comment: the array will have objects with keys `name` & `value`... so you will have to iterate through the array to check for the `name` id to find the value of `id` - or use a simple jQuery selector like `var id = $('input[name="id"]').val();` if the `id` field is an `input` element with `name="id"`

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?  is the .success() function getting called?  I don't think deferred objects have a success function

Comment: ah ok, yeah it's actually undefined at the section var id = postData["id"]...how do I get the id field from the post data parameters?

Comment: @RichardG look at the second part of my comment... `var id = $('input[name="id"]').val();` ... can you share the markup for the `id` field

Comment: ok thanks Arun, got it and it worked. That's frustrating I'd been trying all sorts of things, and the answer was so simple...

Comment: @RichardG sometimes it is those simple things....

Comment: @RichardG you can use `console.log` and `debugger` keywords to debug your `JavaScript` code, they are 2 time-saver and you'll spot problems like this one within seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with the variable, but with the value assigned to it.

Try

```
var id = $('input[name="id"]').val();
```

The problem is serializeArray() returns an array so `postData` is an array not an object so `postData["id"]` should return `undefined` which might be your problem.